# Create xml from xsd with xlinq

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, xsd, linq-to-xml

How do I generate, based on a xsd and c#, an xml containing only the mandatory elements. I would prefer to use xlinq but I am also open to alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a single fiexed xsd? Or is the xsd determined at runtime? With a fixed xsd, you could map it to an object model and use `XmlSerializer`:

```
xsd foo.xsd /classes
```

(at the command line; generates foo.cs with classes for entities etc)

Then build your object-model, and use `XmlSerializer` to serialize it. It *might* work - but isn't a suitable option for working with xsd on the fly.